# Material UI List scroll doesn't reset when list data changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple list of items.

```
      <List>
        {this.state.initialList.map((item, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} button>
            <ListItemText primary={item} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
```

If I scroll to the bottom of the list and load a new list, the scroll stays at the bottom. How do I scroll back to the top of the list?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-l4i3s

In this sandbox, scroll to the bottom, click on "load", the list is showing the last item of the new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a default setting you can set with material-ui to do this. But you definitely can apply some React functionality to get this to work.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8ftqz

Create a ref which would point to the top of the list:

```
  topOfList = React.createRef();
```

Then in your List Component, return a span at the top of the list. Give that span the ref you crated.

```
      <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
        {<span ref={this.topOfList} />}
        {this.state.initialList.map((item, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} button>
            <ListItemText primary={item} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
```

Create an additional handler that scrolls to the element/ref:

```
  scrollToTop = () => {
    if (this.topOfList.current) {
      this.topOfList.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  };
```

Lastly, use the handler inside the set-state call-back to ensure you scroll-up after the data has loaded.

```
this.setState({ initialList: newList }, () => this.scrollToTop())
```

Comment: I'm not too found of scrollIntoView. I already have an annoying bug in Firefox with it.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll is caused by the parent div. 
You can hold a ref to that div, and on load, use the function scorllTo() to position the scrollbar to the top.

```
 <div ref={ref => this.divRef = ref} class="mylist">
          <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
            {this.state.initialList.map((item, index) => (
              <ListItem key={index} button>
                <ListItemText primary={item} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
 </div>
```

and than in load function:

```
  load = () => {
    const newList = [
      "new1",
      "new2",
      "new3",
      "new4",
      "new5",
      "new6",
      "new7",
      "new8",
      "new9",
      "new0"
    ];
    this.divRef.scrollTo(0,0);
    this.setState({ initialList: newList });
  };
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-msyrv?fontsize=14) example

Comment: You forgot to modify the sandbox?

Comment: @gyc yes, sorry. I updated the answer with the right link